# Is this fact needed in the proof regarding division rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am studying the proof that non-trivial finite division rings are fields. The particular proof in question can be found here: [Finite Division Rings are Fields](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hfinkeln/seminarium/eindige_delingsring_is_lichaam.pdf)

In the proof (between top of page 24 and before equation (1)) they make a note that there are equivalence classes of size greater than or equal to 2. This fact is indeed true, but why do we need this fact? I have skimmed the proof a few times now and do not see anywhere the fact is needed. I am asking if someone would kindly look at the proof and let me know if they see where this condition is necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

At the top of page 26, the author writes

$$x^n-1=(x^{n_k}-1)\Psi_n(x)\prod_{d\mid n,d\nmid n_k,d<n}\Psi_d(x).$$

This equation holds since $n_k$ is a proper divisor of $n$. We only know $n_k<n$ because $|A_k|>1$.

Answer (score 1):

The key moment is when the author writes 
$$|R^*| = |Z^*| + \sum_{k=1}^t|A_k|$$
with $t\geqslant 1$. There the $|A_k|$ in the sum are exactly those that are strictly greater than $1$, since those which are equal to $1$ were regrouped in $|Z^*|$.

It then becomes
$$q^n-1 = q-1 + \sum_{k=1}^t\frac{q^n-1}{q^{n_k}-1}$$
with $\frac{q^n-1}{q^{n_k}-1}>1$, and the fact that there are indeed such terms (in other words that $t\geqslant 1$) is crucial.

Comment: I believe the class equation still holds even if |A_k|=1, but since they are all size greater than 1, I do see why $\frac{q^n-1}{q^{n_k}-1}>1$. Could you kindly explain why this part is crucial?

Comment: One way to see it is that the fact that those terms exist forces $n>1$, since $q^n-1>q-1$. And the fact that $n>1$ is implicitly used when showing that $\Phi_n(q)$ cannot divide $q-1$ (if $n=1$, then $\Phi_1(q)=q-1$).

Comment: But we are assuming $\exists s\in R$ such that $s\notin Z(R)$ (center of $R$). This fact alone forces $n>1$. Is this fact related to $n_k\neq n$ for all $k$?